# jQuery Split comma separate and enclose them

Tags: html, jquery

I want to split the letters from `<div class="ltr">a,b,c,d</div>` then enclose them with html codes.

My code:

```
var ltrs = $('.ltr').text();
var string = ltrs.split(",");
```

Then I want to enclose each letter with `<ul><li>Letter here<li></ul>`.

Sample results:

```
<ul><li>a</li></ul>
<ul><li>b</li></ul>
<ul><li>c</li></ul>
<ul><li>d</li></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```js
var ltrs = $('.ltr').text();
var splitted = ltrs.split(',')
var divs = splitted.map(splitted => `<ul><li>${splitted}</li></ul>`)
```

Comment: The result is <ul><li>${splitted}</li></ul>,<ul><li>${splitted}</li></ul>,<ul><li>${splitted}</li></ul>,<ul><li>${splitted}</li></ul>,<ul><li>${splitted}</li></ul>,<ul><li>${splitted}</li></ul>,<ul><li>${splitted}</li></ul>,<ul><li>${splitted}</li></ul>,<ul><li>${splitted}</li></ul>,<ul><li>${splitted}</li></ul>,<ul><li>${splitted}</li></ul>,<ul><li>${splitted}</li></ul>,<ul><li>${splitted}</li></ul>

Comment: @user3835444 You used the wrong quotes. Use ` or `'<ul><li>' + splitted + '</li></ul>'`

Comment: You're missing the closing `)` on the `map()`; `var divs = splitted.map(splitted => `<ul><li>${splitted}</li></ul>`)`

Comment: @mateonunez if you create a working snippet you can demonstrate it working, and will ensure there aren't any silly mistakes like those highlighted above

Answer (score 1):

Use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to loop through each `split()` result, and add the hTML code.

```js
var all = $('.ltr').text().split(',');
var res = all.map(s => `<ul><li>${s}</li></ul>`);

$('.result').html(res); // Just to show the result
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ltr">a,b,c,d</div>

<div class="result"></div> <!-- Just to show the result -->
```